# Python two dimentional array output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started learning python. I come from C++/Java background. To understand two dimensional arrays. I have written the following snippet

```
x = [[0]*3]*3
for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      x[i][j] = i+j

for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      print x[i][j],
   print ""
```

Why is this program printing

```
2 3 4
2 3 4
2 3 4
```

instead of my expectation

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
```

I thought about the reason for this and I am not able to conclude anything. Is this something to do with reference variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us walk through the first statement

```
>>> x = [0]
>>> id(x)
139705127800200
>>> id(x[0])
40157552
```

Note down this id `40157552`. Now when we multiply it by 3. You can see the addresses of the others

```
>>> y = x*3
>>> for i in y:
...     print id(i)
... 
40157552
40157552
40157552
>>> y
[0, 0, 0]
```

All have the same id `40157552`. So this is the reason of your failure to get the correct output.

You can create 2d arrays like already mentioned or you can try the module [`numpy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) by

```
numpy.zeros((3,3)).
```

This creates the exact array you want.

Now for a small demo

```
x = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      x[i][j] = i+j

for i in range(0,3):
   for j in range(0,3):
      print x[i][j],
   print ""
```

This will print

```
0 1 2 
1 2 3 
2 3 4
```

as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't create a 3d array with multiple it on 3 , because actually you crate 3 reference to one object . instead use the following :

```
x = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]
```